# Checking if a String is contained in an Enum Set in O(1)

Tags: java, enums

Let's say I have an enum like the following:

```
public enum Utils {
    UTIL_1, UTIL_2, ... UTIL_n
}
```

Now, I have `Set<Utils> myUtils`, which contains a bunch of these enum entries. Some other module (on which I don't have any control) gives me one such util name (say "`UTIL_i`") as a String. I need to check if it is contained in the set `myUtils`. Is there any way to perform this operation in O(1)? I understand, I could change the set to be a set of Strings, and then do a *.contains()* on that, but I want to keep it as a last resort.

**Update**:
Following the suggestions in the answer, I tried a little experiment. I created a small code snippet to generate a java file which contains an enum of a fixed size. I tried with size 1000, 2500, 5000. An enum of size 10000 showed me the error `The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit`in Eclipse, which is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468388/maximum-number-of-enum-elements-in-java#4468450). I created a Set `myUtils` and pushed all the elements from the Enum to that set. For each of these different size `myUtils` I executed a snippet 1000 times, which looks like `myUtils.contains(Utils.valueOf(<elementName>))`. The average execution time of that code snippet in ms is given below:

**Enum size=1000**

```
UTIL_1     search duration = 1704ms
UTIL_500   search duration = 2316ms
UTIL_1000  search duration = 1732ms
```

**Enum size=2500**

```
UTIL_1     search duration = 2326ms
UTIL_1250  search duration = 1886ms
UTIL_2500  search duration = 1860ms
```

**Enum size=5000**

```
UTIL_1     search duration = 2569ms
UTIL_2500  search duration = 2709ms
UTIL_5000  search duration = 2361ms
```

It clearly shows the average execution time of `Enum.valueOf(String element)` increases with the size of the enum, but I'm not sure of the time complexity of this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the choices is to use the `valueOf` method of `enum` but it's time complexity depends on the input which you'll be using.

If most of your **inputs are nonconvertible** to `Utils` enum then making a `set` and using `contains` method is best approach as `valueOf` method doesn't work well with values which are nonconvertible.

References:
[Java enum valueOf efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164906/java-enum-valueof-efficiency)

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the String into an actual `Utils` member via `Utils util = Utils.valueOf(String)`, and then check if it is contained in the set via `myUtils.contains(util)` which AFAIK is a O(1) operation.

Of course you should check for exceptions in case the String you got doesn't actually correspond to any `Utils`. In your example, it wouldn't, because it should be in uppercase like the enum names.

```
public enum Utils {
    UTIL_1, UTIL_2, ... UTIL_n
}

//...

String utilName = someOtherModuleRoutine();
try {
    if (myUtils.contains(Utils.valueOf(utilName))) {
        // found!
    } else {
        // not found :(
    }
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // utilName is not an actual Utils name
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. That "Utils_1" was an overlook on my end, I intended it to be in uppercase. I'll edit my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to extend your Enum to add the string identifier from the other module. Also, I will write a method to translate a String to a Util enum.

```
public enum Utils {

    UTIL_1("Utils_1"),

    UTIL_2("Utils_2"),

    UTIL_3("Utils_3");

    private final String name;

    private Utils(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public static Utils of(final String name) {
        if (name != null) {
            for (final Utils util : Utils.values()) {
                if (util.getName().equals(name)) {
                    return util;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

To work with Collections of Enums you should use EnumSet or EnumMap. Then you can do something like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String utilName = "Utils_1";
    final Utils utilFromModule = Utils.of(utilName);

    final Set<Utils> utils = EnumSet.of(Utils.UTIL_1, Utils.UTIL_2);
    utils.contains(utilFromModule);
}
```

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect a minor modification. In this case, I think the operation is O(n), because of the for loop.